# Managing application with shared library

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-libraries

I'm working on an application that can be managed with a shared library. I've created an interface class, in this class there are some virtual methods/members. For example there is a method named `Initialize()`, if you want to implement something at the start, you should override this method.

Now I want to make a event/callback like system for managing application. How? If you want to log a message to console+log file, you'll call a method like `Log("Failed to initialize MySQL")` but I can't do it with a interface. I've tried something like that but I've failed;

```
//ManagerBase Header
class ManagerBase
{
public:
    virtual void Initialize();
    void Log(char* message);
}
//Manager Library
class Manager : public ManagerBase
{
public:
    void Initialize() { Log((char*)"Manager's initialize!"); }
}
```

Can anybody help me improve this implementation?

**EDIT1:** I've implemented "Log()" function in my application. (*like printf("%s", message);*) ***When I compile Manager Library, compiler says "Log() method not implemented!"***

**EDIT2:** [Here is my codes](http://pastebin.com/KQiYqbFQ), if someone wants to look them inside.

**EDIT3:** I'm getting this error while I'm trying to compile Manager library: ***undefined reference to `ManagerBase::Log(char*)' [in Manager.cpp]***

Comment: What does your implementation look like?

Comment: @bash.d _like printf("%s", message);_ in application.

Comment: We need to see how it looks like in your implementation file.. I care about the syntax, not the contents.

Comment: @bash.d Ok, maybe I'm doing something wrong. (I've updated post, codes link posted _EDIT2_)

Comment: Have you tried to use `using ManagerBase::Log;` in Manager class?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but are you compiling ManagerBase.cpp ?

Comment: @Kindread ManagerBase.cpp is compiling in application, not in Manager library then I can't compile manager. I need some help to implement a callback/event like function call hieararchy.

Comment: @bash.d Same thing, also I've tried already.

Comment: Just trying to solve your compile error right now. If I compile your code it compiles with no errors, as long as I take out the managerbase.h include from main.cpp ( you might want to use some form of include guard ). Usually when I see someone has a undefined reference error but they have defined the code, its because they forgot to add the cpp to their project in their IDE.

Comment: @Kindread I will not share `ManagerBase.cpp` with manager library. Namely manager developer's only have `ManagerBase.h`, that is the problem already. Developer know "There is a Log function, I can use", he don't know what's inside. Already Log function is being defined in application. I'll compile application once, after I'll use my application with manager, without `ManagerBase.cpp`

Comment: Ah ok. I get your meaning now. But then what are you trying to accomplish ? If you want to define the logging behaviour separate from Manager, using composition rather than inheritance would be cleaner.

Comment: @Kindread That's a special data management program indeed but I want to make a management interface to manage it.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want your event/callback to work, from the application's point of view ? The log function you have isn't displaying the traditional meaning of event/callback. Do you mean that your manager needs to be able to execute behaviour defined by your application ?

Comment: @Kindread "Do you mean that your manager needs to be able to execute behaviour defined by your application?" absolutely! For example there is a method in app named _CreateDB(char* db_name);_, if developer wants to create a database via library, he should call _CreateDB()_ method. This method is working in application, this method will be executed in application. Can you help me about this implemention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the better fit for this is [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Rather than attempting to define the variable behaviour in your base class (ManagerBase), you can have Manager define when the behaviour should occur, and pass that behaviour into Manager as its own object. ManagerBase is no longer needed.

```
// *** Behaviour interfaces ***
// ILogger.h
class ILogger
{
public:
  ~ILogger(){};

  virtual void Log( const char *pMessage ) = 0;
};

//*******************************

// IDatabse.h
class IDatabase
{
public:
  ~IDatabase(){}

  virtual void CreateDB( const char *pDBName ) = 0;
};

//*******************************
// ** Manager **
// Manager.h

class ILogger;
class IDatabase;

class CManager
{
public:
  CManager( 
    ILogger &logger,  
    IDatabase &db );  

  void Initialise( const char *pDBName );

private:
  ILogger &m_logger;
  IDatabase &m_db;
};

// Manager.cpp
#include "ILogger.h"
#include "IDatabase.h"

#include "Manager.h"

CManager::CManager( ILogger &logger, IDatabase &db )
  : m_logger(logger) // this is like registering a Log callback
  , m_db(db)         // and a (set of) db callback/s
{
}

void CManager::Initialise( const char *pDBName )
{ 
  m_logger.Log( "Initialising" ); // this is akin to raising a log 'event'

  m_db.CreateDB( pDBName ); // and a create DB event.
}

//*******************************
// ** Application **
// Application.h
#include "ILogger.h"
#include "IDatabase.h"
#include "Manager.h"

class CApp : public ILogger, public IDatabase
{
/* You don't have to have your main app inherit the interface. You could
   implement them as their own objects, owned by CApp, or at least
   something that is reachable when contructing CManager */
public:
  CApp()
  : m_Manager( *this, *this )
  {
    m_Manager.Initialise("MyAwesomeDatabaseOfDoom");
  } 

  // implement overrides for Log and CreateDB here.
  void Log( const char* pMessage ){}

  void CreateDB( const char *pDBName ){}

private:
  CManager m_Manager;
};

//*******************************
// ** Application **
// main.cpp

int main()
{ 
  CApp();
  return 0;
};
```

This is just a quick mock up, so apologies if it doesn't compile. I hope it at least illustrates the idea.

If you want to be able to change your behaviour at runtime, you can use ILogger/IDatabase member pointers rather than references in CManager, and expose setters so that you can set whatever behaviour defining object you like. This lets you do interesting things like, for example, changing what you log to based on a config file setting, by implementing a CFileLogger and a CDatabaseLogger version of ILogger and setting them appropriately.

Comment: In the manager library: `Manager.cpp line 14-16: undefined references to ILogger, IDatabase` In the application: `Application.h line 12-14, Manager.h line 4-7-16` Did you tried to compile them?

Comment: Hi. I just did a quick mockup. However judging from the error, you need to implement Log and CreateDatabase where I put the comment that says 'implement overrides for Log and CreateDB here'. I see I was also inconsistent with my name for IDatabase, sometimes I called it IDB. Will edit that.

Comment: Oh, I can't implement it again :/ (I'm newbie sorry) Can you help me about this again? _expected unqualified-id before 'public'  (Application.h line 6)_ **EDIT:** I've tried to implement overrides like this: `void ILogger::Log(const char* pMessage){ }`

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I've run it through a compiler, fixed the issues, and edited the post.

Comment: It works! Perfectly! Thanks a lot! I wasn't looking for better one!